# I have troubles while filtering by year and month in Django

Tags: python, django, django-filter

I'm trying to filter queryset by month and date

Here is a code:

```
class FinalListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = FinalSerializer
    filter_backends = [django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend]

    def get_queryset(self):
        condition = Q()
        queryset = Final.objects.all()
        month = self.request.query_params.getlist('month')
        year = self.request.query_params.getlist('year')

    if month:
        if month != 'all':
            for a in month:
                condition |= Q(created_at__month=a)
            queryset = queryset.filter(condition)
            print (queryset)
    if year:
        if year != 'all':
            for a in year:
                condition |= Q(created_at__year=a)
            queryset = queryset.filter(condition)
            print (queryset)
            
        
    return queryset
```

When I'm filtering by year, it returns 200 response, but 0 objects

When I'm filtering by month, I can't even get a 200 response, it returns 500 response

Comment: Can you share the url?

Comment: @ToniSredanović http://127.0.0.1:8000/final/?month=01 AND http://127.0.0.1:8000/final/?year=2020

Comment: month should be 1, not 01

Comment: @token I tried with 1, returned 500 response and I still get 0 object when I filter by year

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist) `getlist` returns a list (in your case of all months or years which are supplied in url).

You can use [__in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#in) to filter by a list of values.

With that in mind you can try this:

```
class FinalListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = FinalSerializer
    filter_backends = [django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend]

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Final.objects.all()
        months = self.request.query_params.getlist('month')
        years = self.request.query_params.getlist('year')

        if months and 'all' not in months:
            queryset = queryset.filter(created_at__month__in=months)
            print (queryset)
        if years and 'all' not in years:
            queryset = queryset.filter(created_at__year__in=years)
            print (queryset)

    return queryset
```

Send requests like so: GET `/final/?month=1`, GET `/final/?year=2020`, ...

Comment: Do values from the query parameters have to be converted to integers?

Comment: No, it should work if they remain as strings.

Comment: @ToniSredanović "GET /final/?year=2020 HTTP/1.1" 500 95043

Comment: The whole traceback, error lines before that too.

Comment: I had a typo on this line: `if years and 'all' not in years:`

Comment: @ToniSredanović I corrected your typo but still I got [link](https://pastebin.com/QxYfLPUw)